# Redis is ZINCRBY atomic?

Tags: redis, mutex, atomic

I am building a leaderboard implementation using redis.

My question is if ZINCRBY is an atomic actions an can be used without a separate mutex or something in a multithreaded environment?

the documentation of [ZINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby) does not mention anything about atomic implemtnation as [the documentation of INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr) does for INCR, INCRBY and DECR

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, ZINCRBY is atomic. There is no need for external synchronization.

Redis is effectively single threaded. Even if two threads send commands to Redis concurrently, Redis will only execute them in a serial order.

Comment: thanks a lot! saves me a lot of effort! will upvote you later when I have enough reputation